# Preview IPython result / output

Tags: python, ipython

Is it possible to preview the result of a computation of IPython, before executing it? For example in the Node REPL, I can do:

[image: node-repl]

However, the same thing does not work in `ipython`

[image: ipython]

I am using ipython, not jupyter. Thank you!

Comment: node to display result also has to execute it - but it seems it does it automatically. I don't see sense for this.